# Логировние добавления/удаления реакций на сообщениях в дискдоре

Tags: discord

столькнулся с проблемой логирования изменений реакций на сообщениях в дискдоре, ничего не нашёл вообще

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

покажу на примере javascript
Вы можете использовать messageReactionRemove() событие .

```
client.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) => {
  console.log(`${user.username} unreacted ${reaction.emoji.name} on this message: ${reaction.message.content}`)
```